# Get index/rank of document in "aggregation pipeline"

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a collection with 8 documents. "**Using Aggregation Pipeline**" How to create "index" field for every document that start with 1,2,3,4,...,8.

```
{
   "index": 1
},
{
   "index": 2
},
{
   "index": 3
},
.
.
.
{
   "index": 8
}
```

Comment: You really cannot. MongoDB has no "Oracle like" [ROWNUM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) functionality. You can implement in a "highly inefficient and impractical way" using the `includeArrayindex` option of [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). But this in general not practical since it would involve pushing all results into an array of a single document and then "unwinding". This just about always breaks the BSON limit in all real use cases.

Comment: If however your intention is for a "ranking" and probably based on "sorting" a given value in the document, then the approach to this can be done quite simply using `.count()` and the usage of a "range query" to effectively count the documents that preceded the present selection. But as a general inclusion in returned results you cannot do this. You should probably state your use case more clearly so you can be pointed to the correct alternate solution.